# Name from textbox is not echoing from php

Tags: php, html, post, switch-statement, html-select

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Greeting Service!</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post" action="">
<h1>What's Your Name?</h1>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name Here" />
<h4>Greet me in:
<select name="language">
<option value="option1">English</option>
<option value="option2">Chinese</option>
<option value="option3">French</option>
</select>
</h4>
<input type="submit" value="Greet Me!" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['language'])) {
switch ($language) {
case "option1":
$result = "Hello, $name!"; 
break;
case "option2":
$result = "你好, $name!"; 
break;
case "option3":
$result = "Bonjour, $name!"; 
break;
}
}
?>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't display the name i enter in from the input text box with the greeting according to each different language. I have used $_POST to submit the form and used a `switch` and `case` in my php code. Can someone help me out, i would like the name that is entered in the textbox to display when i have chosen which language i want the greeting to come out with. Thanks.

Comment: Because `$name` is not assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `$language` defined. What you should use is `$_POST['language']` :

```
if (isset($_POST['language'])) {
switch ($_POST['language']) {
```

EDIT: didn't notice the `$name` variable as said by Meenesh Jain.
And the last thing: you never do anything with the result. Not sure if that's intended or not, but I would add an `echo $result;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`$name` is not defined

change your code like this

```
 if (isset($_POST['language'])) {
switch ($_POST['language']) {
case "option1":
$result = "Hello, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
case "option2":
$result = "你好, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
case "option3":
$result = "Bonjour, {$_POST['name']}!"; 
break;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: using `$_POST['name']` in double quotes without curly brackets `{}` may invoke a syntax warning. see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex. May want to do `{$_POST['name']}` or `$_POST[name]` (without the single quotes around the key)

Comment: i prefer it outside the double quotes with string concatination `"hello ". $_POST['name']` like this

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not initializing any value to **$language**
just place code like `$language = $_POST['language'];`
above the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

declare a varibale `$name` and assign `$_POST['name']` to it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Greeting Service!</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post" action="">
<h1>What's Your Name?</h1>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name Here" />
<h4>Greet me in:
<select name="language">
<option value="option1">English</option>
<option value="option2">Chinese</option>
<option value="option3">French</option>
</select>
</h4>
<input type="submit" value="Greet Me!" />
<?php
if (isset($_POST['language'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
switch ($language) {
case "option1":
$result = "Hello, $name!"; 
break;
case "option2":
$result = "你好, $name!"; 
break;
case "option3":
$result = "Bonjour, $name!"; 
break;
}
}
?>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

tried using php to solve your question but could not get it through but Javascript does it seamlessly. Tested though. Find code below

```
<center>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
<h1>What's Your Name?</h1>
<input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Name Here" id="myName"/>
<h4>Greet me in:
    <select name="lang" onchange="getValue()" id="language">
        <option value="English">English</option>
        <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
        <option value="French">French</option>
    </select>
</h4>
<input type="submit" value="Greet Me!" />

<div id="show"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function getValue(){
        var myName = document.getElementById("myName").value;
        var lang =  document.getElementById("language").value;

        if(myName == null){
            document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "No name selected";
        }
        else{
            switch(lang) {
                case 'English':
                    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Hello" + ' ' + myName;
                    break;
                case 'Chinese':
                    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "你好" + ' ' + myName;
                    break;
                case 'French':
                    document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = "Bonjour" + ' ' + myName;
                    break;

            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Copied the code and replace it where you have same.
Glad i could help.